# what target flag should I set to cross compile arm 32 bit code in gcc?

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation, binutils

I'm trying to build a cross compiling build server for some 32 bit arm devices, where the architecture is:
(from uname -m) "armv5tejl"
I have to specify the target for binutils, and gcc, which looking like:
--target=aarch64-linux
(for example)
should I expect that the target flag for my use case is
--target=armv5tejl-linux
?
or how would I know the target flag to use?

I tried looking in $`gcc --target-help| less`
for help, but I dont see anything of use.

Answer (score 1):

The `armv5tejl` from `uname` represents the ARM v5TEJ architecture and specifically the [ARM926EJ-S CPU](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0198/e/introduction/about-the-arm926ej-s-processor).

To compile for this cpu use:

```
% /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -o hello hello.c
```

You may run into library issues. Compiling the binary to be static (not use dynamic libraries) may be desired. Use this:

```
% /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -mcpu=arm926ej-s -o hello hello.c
```